# Inbox message for a question I have nothing to do with

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just received an inbox message regarding a [question on StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/why-cant-area51-be-associated) that I never had anything to do with.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbox message relates to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54609/area-51-related-accounts-not-working) which was closed as a duplicate of [this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/why-cant-area51-be-associated)

You asked the initial question (and is actually where the comment is) hence why you get the notification.

I guess SE have implemented some redirection based on the whether the question is closed or not. As this is a duplicate it automagically redirects you to the new question. I guess that should not happen for requests from the inbox.

EDIT:

[This MSO Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146561/disable-the-automatic-redirect-to-duplicates-when-the-referrer-is-an-se-site) is a duplicate, of sorts, of this question as it highlights this behaviour already.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was confused, as I don’t see my question.